# Qt5 opens multiple window

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-sdk, qt5

I recently installed **qt5** and **ubuntu sdk** and i use 13.04 . In welcome section when i click develop,example or tutorial tabs multiple windows open up and I am unable to close it.
How do i fix this.

I checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340547/ubuntu-sdk-graphics-glitch-on-13-04) page but is of no use

Answer (score 0):

This is a know (annoying) bug. Delete /home/kknd/.config/QtProject/QtCreator.ini and disable the welcome plugin in QtCreator -> About -> Plugins, and it should work.

You can also try QtCreator 2.8.1, download the package [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/ubuntu_sdk_release/saucy/main/base/qtcreator).